# programming a sniffer for AES GCM with gcrypt

Tags: aes, gcm

I want to write a sniffer that can read AES-GCM communication using the gcrypt lib
 I can see in the manual that for encryption there is an additional 2 methods (for AEAD)
but what about decryption ? what need to do for decryption for AEAD ciphers ? 
Thanks
Lior

Comment: Encryption and decryption is the same for GCM (as it uses CTR for encryption)

Comment: Are you asking how to do it with gcrypt? That's off topic here and could be asked on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @otus, on "Stack Exchange" is a bit misleading. I guess you meant StackOverflow.

Comment: @SEJPM, yes, typo/brainfart.

Comment: I see at least three methods specifically for AEAD...getting the tag, checking the tag and indicating additional authenticated data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `gcry_cipher_authenticate` if you have additional authenticated data (data also authenticated that is not encrypted and - in this case after decryption of the ciphertext, excluding authentication tag - you should call `gcry_cipher_checktag` with the authentication tag. It's wise and possibly required to call `gcry_cipher_authenticate` before decryption of any data.

You should not rely on the correctness of the decrypted data before verifying (checking) the authentication tag. Note that the handling of the authentication tag differs from one library to the other (and this library actually takes the sensible route if you ask me: fully online decryption and explicit tag verification).